# Remove User interaction from apt-get when installing/removing things in a script

Tags: apt

I have a script which removes libreoffice and installs openoffice instead, how can I get apt-get to stop requiring the user to confirm this operation? I only want this to happen in the script so what switches should I use? I also want to reduce the output so it doesn't clog up the console.

Comment: When you say `stop user confirmation` means just install without responding as a yes to question whether you want it or not? `sudo apt-get install AnyProgramYouWant -y`. `-y` here means yes to all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use `apt-get --yes`. Quoting from the man page (`man apt-get`):

> `-y`, `--yes`, `--assume-yes`
>
> Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run
>   non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as changing a held
>   package, trying to install a unauthenticated package or removing an
>   essential package occurs then apt-get will abort. Configuration Item:
>   `APT::Get::Assume-Yes`.

For example:

```
apt-get install --yes gedit
```

To reduce the output you can redirect it to `/dev/null` (only errors will be shown):

```
apt-get install --yes gedit > /dev/null
```

To make it produce zero output (not even print errors):

```
apt-get install --yes gedit &> /dev/null
```

Then, if something goes wrong, you will be able to find information in `/var/log/apt`.