# User interaction free apt-get in ubuntu

Tags: apt, cron, amazon-ec2, aws

So I read the answer to the question here. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

[Remove User interaction from apt-get when installing/removing things in a script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233741/remove-user-interaction-from-apt-get-when-installing-removing-things-in-a-script)

But my problem is different. When I use:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

It runs untill certain extent but then I get this screen.

[image]

I want to keep the local version installed. Any idea how I can achieve this without user interaction. I am planning to run a cron job for the above command but it is failing due to above user interaction required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct answer is. There is a current bug opened for this [located here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1323772) and it was also present is 12.02 LTS as [seen here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146921/how-do-i-apt-get-y-dist-upgrade-without-a-grub-config-prompt). The steps listed in the bottom of the bug report by Anders Hall do work for the 14.04 LTS 64-bit (HVM) AMI (ami-d05e75b8 in US-EAST-1):

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo rm /boot/grub/menu.lst
$ sudo update-grub-legacy-ec2 -y
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -qq --force-yes
$ sudo reboot
```

Upon reboot the 14.04.2 LTS was upgraded to 14.04.3 LTS and `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` returned 0 new packages.